# System.InvalidCastException on FFDShow Video Decoder on "Standard User" account

Tags: windows, directshow, directshow.net, ffdshow

**Exception:**

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'DirectShowLib.IBaseFilter'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{56A86895-0AD4-11CE-B03A-0020AF0BA770}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

**My Graph:**
Custom File Source (Async.) ->  GDCL Mpeg-4 Demultiplexor ->  ffdshow Video Decoder -> Video Renderer

My graph builds and plays correctly on an Administrator account. However when on a "Standard User" account it throws an exception on casting the [FFDShow](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/) filter.

**Code:**

```
IBaseFilter pffdshowVideoDecoder = (IBaseFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSID_ffdshowVideoDecoder));
```

Creating the instance does not throw an exception, only when i attempt to cast it under Standard User account.

Additional Info:

- My program is set to STAThread
- The creation and casting of the object is on my Main thread

Comment: So I had to switch filters (LAV Filters) because I could not fix the issue.